# php/json riot api blank page failing

Tags: php, json, api

Im new to php and json and usage of API's. Im on a big data project and I want to create a web application that retrieves information from the API in order to create predictive analysis.

I tried to use this code to retrieve data but all I see is a blank page. http://20ff.net/index.php

```
    <html>
 <head>
  <title>RIOT API SBOX</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php 

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.2/matchhistory/31827832?rankedQueues=RANKED_SOLO_5x5&api_key=key'), true);

var_dump(json_decode($json));

echo $json[0]['firstBloodKill'];


 ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Yes, I removed the api key myself, with key its not working also.
Please help me out, are there any basic tutorials how to return information in JSON between php tags?

Comment: Are you getting a json response from `file_get_contents(...)`?

Comment: why are you decoding twice?, the initial `$json` is already decoded

Comment: im a complete amateur when it comes to json/php. I used to program in pl/sql only. How do I check if I get response from file_get_contents? I just removed the 2nd decode.

Comment: As you're using fgc, `ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1);` if it's not already set. Can you give us a sample of what `$json` holds?

Comment: you could `var_dump` your `$json` variable for debugging purpose, and check your php log for warning or errors.

Comment: should I put that line between php tags or do i put it somewhere in the config files?

Comment: Remove this line `$json = json_decode($json,true);` as @Ghost suggests

Comment: I have updated the code and it seems when using var_dump that it returns NULL. you can check the website in my first message.

Comment: That means you are not getting json from this url... var_dump the `file_get_contents` directly

Comment: when I use var_dump(file_get_contents) it returns null also. The api request is 100% valid, i tried it by pasting in adress bar.

Comment: Put this instead : `var_dump(file_get_contents('https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.2/matchhistory/31827832?rankedQueues=RANKED_SOLO_5x5&api_key=key'));` And see the actual content

Comment: returns 'bool(false)'

Comment: @floppy what is the value of `var_dump( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') );`

Comment: Try to add this to see potential errors : `<?php error_reporting(~0);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>` on the top of your code

Comment: I tried, but it still says the same, string(0) ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reasons that aren't clear to me, it looks like the `rankedSoloGamesPlayed` field isn't returned for all champions.  In fact, in your query it's only returned for a single champion (index 21):

```
<?php
$KEY = "<Your API Key>";

$url=sprintf('https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/31827832/ranked?season=SEASON4&api_key=%s', $KEY);
$data=file_get_contents($url);
$json=json_decode($data);

// Uncomment this if you want to see the full decoded JSON
//print_r($json);

echo $json->champions[21]->stats->rankedSoloGamesPlayed;  
// This displays 0, which is the value returned in the JSON

// Additionally, you could access the totalDamageDealt field of the champion with index 0 with:
echo $json->champions[0]->stats->totalDamageDealt;
// This displays 214660
```

Note how you have to traverse the decoded JSON.  If `print_r` says it's an `Array`, you can traverse it with brackets (`[21]`), but if it says it's a stdClass Object, you traverse it with the arrow notation.

Comment: Could create a completel example with php tags included? When I copy paste and edit the key it returns Internal server error. am i missing something?

Comment: It's possible you're missing the opening `<?php` tag -- I originally omitted it but thats about it, other than redacting my API key.  I'll add the opening tag, just make sure you update the API key accordingly (for example, `$KEY="12345...";`)

Comment: I tried with php tags but still failed, i dont know what went wrong.

Comment: From the comments on your question, it looks like you have `allow_url_fopen` off, which will prevent you from using `file_get_contents` to fetch remote files.  You'll need to either enable that (see [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)), or possibly find a workaround ([possibly curl?](http://www.christianschenk.org/blog/php-curl-allow-url-fopen/)).

Comment: That is correct, I went to the iPage host website cpanel and searched for php.ini. I found out that this was active. allow_url_fopen = Off. I changed it to allow_url_fopen = On

or does it need to be changed to allow_url_fopen = Boolean

Comment: I'm not sure how the cpanel is setup, but if it's a dropdown or radio button selection, then choose "On".  If it's a textbox where you enter whatever you want, try simply `1`.

Comment: It is indeed a text box, I have set it to `allow_url_fopen = 1`
But the error message is still there, there must be something else wrong what I am missing.

Comment: Again, I'm not sure how the cpanel is setup, but if it looks like you're directly editing the php.ini, then `allow_url_fopen = on` would be what you want.  Also, for me, I'd have to restart my webserver for these changes to go into effect.  That may not be the case with you -- has the output of `var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'));` changed?

Comment: the result of `var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'));` has changed to `string(1) "1"`

Comment: okay, now add a `var_dump($data);` in there -- preferably on the line after `$data = ...` -- what do you get?

Comment: internal server error again. [http://pastebin.com/9jW4Ss94](http://pastebin.com/9jW4Ss94)

Comment: `$KEY=key` make it `$KEY="key";`. You're missing a semi-colon.

Comment: @floppy Turn on error reporting and display errors. Run your script. Debug. Test. Repeat. Yay it worked.